# Why are the coupling capacitors needed in this DCM converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, emc, coupling

I have a 48V power supply which needs to be converted to a 12V output. I want to achieve this by using the DCM2322 dc/dc converter.

In the [Datasheet](http://www.vicorpower.com/documents/datasheets/DCM2322xA5N13A2y6z_ds.pdf) the following recommended circuit is given:

[image]

My question is why are coupling capacitors needed around the dc/dc converter?

Comment: Which ones are you referring to?

Comment: @Andyaka The capacitors connecting the +input with the +output and the capacitors connecting the -input with the -output

Comment: It looks like the original design didn't foresee the emergence of EMI directives and legislation and these are afterthoughts to fix customer complaints. The data sheet doesn't even mention values for the CY capacitors so it's one of those products that looks to me like it might be a stinker to rely on. I'd look for answers/confidence from Vicor. I don't get it from the data sheet as it stands.